# How to printout string in qemu gumstix (connex/PXA255) emulation?

Tags: arm, qemu

From this site: http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/ 
I can use C code to print out a string in qemu simulator.

```
volatile unsigned int * const UART0DR = (unsigned int *)0x101f1000;
void print_uart0(const char *s) {
 while(*s != '\0') { /* Loop until end of string */
 *UART0DR = (unsigned int)(*s); /* Transmit char */
 s++; /* Next char */
 }
}
```

I need to do the same thing in C code with gumstix connex board in qemu (with -M connex option), which uses `0x40100000` or `0x40700000` for the memory mapped uart address, but nothing is shown in the screen.

[image]
[image]

I tried with some data checking code, but it doesn't still work.

```
volatile unsigned int * const UART0DR = (unsigned int *)0x40100000;
volatile unsigned int * const UART_LSR = (unsigned int *)0x40100014;
#define LSR_TDRQ    (1 << 5)    // Transmit Data Request
void print_uart0(const char *s) {
 while(*s != '\0') { /* Loop until end of string */
    while(( *UART_LSR & LSR_TDRQ ) == 0 ); 
     *UART0DR = (unsigned int)(*s); /* Transmit char */
 s++; /* Next char */
 }
}
```

What might be wrong? Is PXA255 uses different way to use uart?

I searched the source code of [pxa](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/qemu.git/tree/hw/pxa.h), and [gumstix](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/qemu.git/tree/hw/gumstix.c), maybe gumstix may use different methods to do hart communication in qemu.

Comment: Maybe I'm lucky, but from a web search for "gumstix uart", in _two_ clicks I had the [PXA225 developers manual](https://pubs.gumstix.com/documents/PXA%20Documentation/PXA255/PXA255%20Processor%20Developers%20Manual%20%5B278693-002%5D.pdf) up on my screen. That took less time and effort than typing this comment, let alone this question.

Comment: @Notlikethat: I knew about the manual, but I couldn't make it work with the address that I found in the manual. I updated my question.

Answer (score 4):

qemu should be relaxed about the accurate emulation of the UART.
Below code works:

startup.s:

```
.global startup
startup:
   ldr sp, startup_stack_top
   bl c_startup
   b .
startup_stack_top:
   .word 0xa4000000
```

os.c:

```
void write_uart(char *str)
{
    char c;
    volatile char *uart = (char *)0x40100000;
    while (1) {
        c = *str;
        if (!c)
            break;
        *uart = c;
        str++;
    }
}
void c_startup() 
{
    write_uart("hello\r\n");
}
```

linker script os.ld:

```
ENTRY(startup)
SECTIONS
{
   . = 0x0;
   .startup : { startup.o(.text) }
   .text : { *(.text) }
   .rodata : { *(.rodata) }
   .data : { *(.data) }
   .bss : { *(.bss COMMON) }
}
```

Build commands:

```
#pfx=arm-none-eabi-

$(pfx)as -g -march=armv5te startup.s -o startup.o
$(pfx)gcc -g -c -march=armv5te os.c -o os.o
$(pfx)ld -T os.ld os.o startup.o -o os.elf
$(pfx)objcopy -O binary os.elf os.bin
dd of=flash.img bs=128k count=128 if=/dev/zero
dd of=flash.img bs=128k conv=notrunc if=os.bin
```

Run command:

```
qemu-system-arm -M connex -m 128M  -snapshot -pflash flash.img
```

Answer (score 3):

From your linked page you may have noticed the following text:

> The code that emulates the serial port inside QEMU (here in the source repository) implements a subset of the functionalities of the PL011 Prime Cell UART from ARM

and

> The QEMU model of the PL011 serial port ignores the transmit FIFO capabilities; in a real system on chip the “Transmit FIFO Full” flag must be checked in the UARTFR register before writing on the UARTDR register.

You won't be able to use the same code on both QEMU and the PXA255 since the implementation of the UART is different.

To have the UART function correctly on the PXA255 board will require a lot more setup and would typically involve the following:

- Configuration of the clock subsystem registers to ensure that the UART peripheral is receiving a clock from the main clock system on the CPU.
- Configuration of the UART peripheral registers according to the desired use.  You may need to configure registers which control baud rate register, parity control, number of data bits.
- Modification of your code which writes to the UART.  UART peripherals typically contain a FIFO (sometimes just a single byte) which is used during transmission and reception.  To transmit a character you first have to ensure that the previous character has finished transmission before placing the next character for transmit in the output data register.

There is no substitute for reading the UART data sheet in detail and following all the information listed there.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a bunch of other code you aren't showing, you're missing several important things here:

- Clocks and power for the UART module must be enabled before it will function. See section 3 of the PXA255 manual.
- The GPIOs used by the UART must be configured before the UART will work correctly (e.g, by setting appropriate pin directions and alternate functions). See section 4.1 of the PXA255 manual.
- The UART must be configured (e.g, baud rate, etc.) before you start writing data to it. The PXA255 manual does not explicitly include information on these registers; you will need to cross-reference the 16550 datasheet.
- While writing data to the UART, you must ensure the UART is in an appropriate state to receive data (e.g, that the transmit buffer is not full), and wait for it to enter an appropriate state if it is not. Refer to the 16550 datasheet, or to a general tutorial on use of this UART.

The UART implementation in QEMU is intended as a debugging tool, not as a full emulation of the UART in a real device. Just because something works in QEMU doesn't mean it will work on real hardware!

Comment: I guess I didn't make it clear that gumstix board means qemu emulation board.

Answer (score 1):

As Austin Phillips pointed out, it requires a lot of setup code to make it work with UART serial communication. What confused me before was that I could make the UART communication work without any setup with `qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel test.bin`, but this is versatilepb board emulation. My guess is that for versatilepb board, UART setup is just finished before my binary runs.

Mimicking that, what I did was to use a uboot, which does all of the UART setup, and load my binary image from the uboat, and everything works fine.